Fresh NextJS project cannot hit root route, keep getting redirected to home
Pretty straight forward. Inside the app folder there is page.tsx with the default vercel stuff.
If it try and hit http://localhost:3000/ i get redirected to http://localhost:3000/home.
If i put a home folder in the app directory and put page.tsx inside it I cant see the page contents when i navigate to /home.
But even putting a new page.tsx inside app and accessing the root directory / I still get redirected to /home

Can you update with a screenshot of your file structure?

@MelvinKosisochukwu Not sure what happened but i tried to access the route in firefox rather than chrome.
Got the following error. Terminated it in the console and re-ran with pnpm run dev. Now its running on port 3001 and i can not access the root route. No idea why though
webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack failed from...
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted...

Try deleting the .next folder, clean cache and run next dev again.

@MelvinKosisochukwu Tested on a different port other than 3000 and with firefox and was no longer getting the redirect. Cleared my chromed browser cache and it's now no longer redirecting me in chrome either. Didn't know cache could cause issues like this.

Yeah, but its not so often.

It was an issue with the browser cache. Cleared it and everything works fine.
